# How do I place the avatar in the extreme Right?

Tags: html, css

[Click to open the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgBpf.png)

[Click to visit website](https://newwebsite.deepjyoti7147.repl.co/)

I want the avatar image to align with the right side of the screen but it's not aligning. I have tried `text-align` but that's also not workinh

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Slab:wght@100&family=Ubuntu:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,400&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
body {
  background: #5cdb95;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
}


#preloader{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10000;
  background: #f1f2f3;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

/* navbar starts */
header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 1.7rem 10%;
  height: 6.5rem;
  background-color: #5cdb95;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px #379683;
}
section {
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 2rem 9%;
}
.heading {
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  color: #05386b;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-align: center;
}
.heading span {
  color: rgb(115, 3, 167);
}
header .logo {
  font-size: 1.9rem;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #05386b;
}
header .logo i {
  font-size: 2.2rem;
}
header .logo:hover {
  color: #edf5e1;
}
header .navbar ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
header .navbar li {
  margin-left: 2.5rem;
}
header .navbar ul li a {
  font-size: 1.57rem;
  color: #05386b;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 0.04rem;
  transition: 0.2s;
}
header .navbar ul li a.active,
header .navbar ul li a:hover {
  color: #edf5e1;
  border-bottom: 0.2rem solid #edf5e1;
  padding: 0.5rem 0;
}
/* navbar ends */


/* hero section starts*/
.home {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 1.5rem;
  min-height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
}
.home #particles-js {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.home::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.home .content {
  flex: 1 1 40rem;
  padding-top: 1rem;
  z-index: 1;
}

.home .image {
  flex: 1 1 40rem;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-left: auto;
  display: block;
}
.home .image img {
  width: 80%;
  display: block;
  float:right;
}

.home .content h2 {
  font-size: 5rem;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: #edf5e1;
}
.home .content h2 span {
  font-size: 5rem;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: #05386b;
}
.home .content p {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 1rem 0;
}
.home .content p span {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  color: rgb(148, 8, 8);
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 1rem 0;
}
.home .btn {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 0;
  padding: 1.6rem 3rem;
  border-radius: 4em;
  transition: 0.5s;
  color: #fff;
  background: #2506ad;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 18px rgba(48, 68, 247, 0.6);
  font-family: "Nunito", sans-serif;
}
.home .btn span {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
}
.home .btn i {
  margin-left: 0.3rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.home .btn:hover {
  background: #1a047e;
}
.home .btn:hover i {
  transform: translateX(5px);
}
/* social icons start */
.socials {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 9rem;
}
.socials .social-icons {
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.socials .social-icons li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 14px;
}
.social-icons a {
  font-size: 2rem;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 44px;
  color: #00d9ff;
  background-color: #09011b;
  width: 44px;
  height: 44px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 8px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
.social-icons a:active,
.social-icons a:focus,
.social-icons a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #0685da;
}
.social-icons a.github:hover {
  background-color: #0e0e0e;
}
.social-icons a.twitter:hover {
  background-color: #00aced;
}
.social-icons a.linkedin:hover {
  background-color: #007bb6;
}
.social-icons a.dev:hover {
  background-color: #070707;
}
.social-icons a.instagram:hover {
  background-color: #ee00da;
}
/* social icons end */

/* hero media queries starts*/
@media (max-width: 450px) {
  .home .btn {
    margin: 4rem 0;
  }
  .socials {
    margin-top: 12rem;
  }
  .home .image img {
    margin-top: -12rem;
  }
  .home .content p {
    font-size: 2.2rem;
  }
  .home .content p span {
    font-size: 2.2rem;
  }
}
/* hero media queries ends*/
/* hero section end */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>Deepjyoti's Portfolio</title>
      <link id='favicon' rel="shortcut icon" href="static/images/favicon.jpg" type="image/x-jpg">
      <link href="static/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
      <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/24a4de0b47.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="preloader"class="loader-container">
         <img draggable="false" src="static/images/preloader.gif" alt="" width=100px height=100px >
      </div>
      <!-- navbar starts -->
      <header>
         <a href="/" class="logo" ><img draggable="false" class="tilt" src="static/images/logo.gif" style="width:80px;height:auto"; alt=""></a>
         
         <nav class="navbar">
            <ul>
              <div id="menu" class="fas fa-bars fa-2x""></div>
               <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
               <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
               <li><a href="#skills">Skills</a></li>
               <li><a href="#education">Education</a></li>
               <li><a href="#work">Work</a></li>
               <li><a href="#experience">Experience</a></li>
               <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
         </nav>
      </header>
      <!-- navbar ends -->
      <!-- hero section starts -->
      <section class="home" id="home">
         <div id="particles-js"></div>
         <div class="content">
            <h2>Hi There,<br/> I'm Deepjyoti <span>Purkayastha</span></h2>
            <p>i am into <span class="typing-text"></span></p>
            <a href="#about" class="btn"><span>About Me</span>
            <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-down"></i>
            </a>
            <div class="socials">
               <ul class="social-icons">
                  <li><a class="linkedin" aria-label="LinkedIn" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/deepjyoti7147/" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
                  <li><a class="github" aria-label="GitHub" href="https://github.com/deepjyoti7147" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-github"></i></a></li>
                  <li><a class="twitter" aria-label="Twitter" href="https://twitter.com/deepjyoti7147" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                  <li><a class="instagram" aria-label="Instagram" href="https://www.instagram.com/deepjyoti7147"><i class="fab fa-instagram" target="_blank"></i></a></li>
                  <li><a class="dev" aria-label="Dev" href="https://dev.to/deepjyoti7147" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-dev"></i></a></li>
               </ul>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="image">
            <img draggable="false" class="tilt" src="static/images/hero2.png" alt="">
         </div>
      </section>
      <!-- hero section ends -->
      <!--JAVA SCRIPTS -->
      <script src="static/js/script.js"></script>
      
      <!--JAVA SCRIPT END-->
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:web-site-project]? Have you read the description of that tag?

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a [mcve]. If I run the code you provided it shows a blank areal (because you didn't use an image to a real URL like you might find at https://placeholder.com/ ) for the preloader image (not showing the avatar image at all because it is covered up).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your snippet doesnt work but i went to your website and checked your CSS.

Since your image in a container that has a width with limit you gotta use `position:absolute` and then resize the picture with `right` and `top` rulers. But simpy add this code and it will fix your problem. Customize it according to your needs. Don't forget to set different values for mobile version of the website:

```
.home .image img {
    width: 43%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 17%;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: If you have questions feel free to ask

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Slab:wght@100&family=Ubuntu:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,400&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
body {
  background: #5cdb95;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
}


#preloader{
  position: fixed;
  top: 65px;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 10000;
  background: #f1f2f3;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

/* navbar starts */
header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 1.7rem 10%;
  height: 6.5rem;
  background-color: #5cdb95;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px #379683;
}
section {
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 2rem 9%;
}
.heading {
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  color: #05386b;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-align: center;
}
.heading span {
  color: rgb(115, 3, 167);
}
header .logo {
  font-size: 1.9rem;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #05386b;
}
header .logo i {
  font-size: 2.2rem;
}
header .logo:hover {
  color: #edf5e1;
}
header .navbar ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
header .navbar li {
  margin-left: 2.5rem;
}
header .navbar ul li a {
  font-size: 1.57rem;
  color: #05386b;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 0.04rem;
  transition: 0.2s;
}
header .navbar ul li a.active,
header .navbar ul li a:hover {
  color: #edf5e1;
  border-bottom: 0.2rem solid #edf5e1;
  padding: 0.5rem 0;
}
/* navbar ends */


/* hero section starts*/
.home {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 1.5rem;
  min-height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
}
.home #particles-js {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.home::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.home .content {
  flex: 1 1 40rem;
  padding-top: 1rem;
  z-index: 1;
}

.home .image {
  flex: 1 1 40rem;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-left: auto;
  display: block;
}
.home .image img {
  width: 80%;
  display: block;
  float:right;
}

.home .content h2 {
  font-size: 5rem;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: #edf5e1;
}
.home .content h2 span {
  font-size: 5rem;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: #05386b;
}
.home .content p {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 1rem 0;
}
.home .content p span {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  color: rgb(148, 8, 8);
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 1rem 0;
}
.home .btn {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 0;
  padding: 1.6rem 3rem;
  border-radius: 4em;
  transition: 0.5s;
  color: #fff;
  background: #2506ad;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 18px rgba(48, 68, 247, 0.6);
  font-family: "Nunito", sans-serif;
}
.home .btn span {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
}
.home .btn i {
  margin-left: 0.3rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.home .btn:hover {
  background: #1a047e;
}
.home .btn:hover i {
  transform: translateX(5px);
}
/* social icons start */
.socials {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 9rem;
}
.socials .social-icons {
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.socials .social-icons li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 14px;
}
.social-icons a {
  font-size: 2rem;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 44px;
  color: #00d9ff;
  background-color: #09011b;
  width: 44px;
  height: 44px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 8px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
.social-icons a:active,
.social-icons a:focus,
.social-icons a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #0685da;
}
.social-icons a.github:hover {
  background-color: #0e0e0e;
}
.social-icons a.twitter:hover {
  background-color: #00aced;
}
.social-icons a.linkedin:hover {
  background-color: #007bb6;
}
.social-icons a.dev:hover {
  background-color: #070707;
}
.social-icons a.instagram:hover {
  background-color: #ee00da;
}
/* social icons end */

/* hero media queries starts*/
@media (max-width: 450px) {
  .home .btn {
    margin: 4rem 0;
  }
  .socials {
    margin-top: 12rem;
  }
  .home .image img {
    margin-top: -12rem;
  }
  .home .content p {
    font-size: 2.2rem;
  }
  .home .content p span {
    font-size: 2.2rem;
  }
}
/* hero media queries ends*/
/* hero section end */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>Deepjyoti's Portfolio</title>
      <link id='favicon' rel="shortcut icon" href="static/images/favicon.jpg" type="image/x-jpg">
      <link href="static/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
      <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/24a4de0b47.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="preloader"class="loader-container">
         <img draggable="false" src="static/images/preloader.gif" alt="" width=100px height=100px >
      </div>
      <!-- navbar starts -->
      <header>
         <a href="/" class="logo" ><img draggable="false" class="tilt" src="static/images/logo.gif" style="width:80px;height:auto"; alt=""></a>
         
         <nav class="navbar">
            <ul>
              <div id="menu" class="fas fa-bars fa-2x""></div>
               <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
               <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
               <li><a href="#skills">Skills</a></li>
               <li><a href="#education">Education</a></li>
               <li><a href="#work">Work</a></li>
               <li><a href="#experience">Experience</a></li>
               <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
         </nav>
      </header>
      <!-- navbar ends -->
      <!-- hero section starts -->
      <section class="home" id="home">
         <div id="particles-js"></div>
         <div class="content">
            <h2>Hi There,<br/> I'm Deepjyoti <span>Purkayastha</span></h2>
            <p>i am into <span class="typing-text"></span></p>
            <a href="#about" class="btn"><span>About Me</span>
            <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-down"></i>
            </a>
            <div class="socials">
               <ul class="social-icons">
                  <li><a class="linkedin" aria-label="LinkedIn" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/deepjyoti7147/" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
                  <li><a class="github" aria-label="GitHub" href="https://github.com/deepjyoti7147" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-github"></i></a></li>
                  <li><a class="twitter" aria-label="Twitter" href="https://twitter.com/deepjyoti7147" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                  <li><a class="instagram" aria-label="Instagram" href="https://www.instagram.com/deepjyoti7147"><i class="fab fa-instagram" target="_blank"></i></a></li>
                  <li><a class="dev" aria-label="Dev" href="https://dev.to/deepjyoti7147" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-dev"></i></a></li>
               </ul>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="image">
            <img draggable="false" class="tilt" src="static/images/hero2.png" alt="">
         </div>
      </section>
      <!-- hero section ends -->
      <!--JAVA SCRIPTS -->
      <script src="static/js/script.js"></script>
      
      <!--JAVA SCRIPT END-->
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Let me know if this is what you need.